# Emulate deque structure in mongoengine

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

So I have a "section" and each section has a number of "nuggets". My model is this:

```
class Nugget(EmbeddedDocument):
    title = StringField(required=True)
    img = StringField(required=True)
    content = StringField(required=True)
    section = StringField(required=True)
    next_nugget = StringField(required=True)
    previous_nugget = StringField(required=True)

class Section(Document):
    meta = {"collection":"Sections"}
    title = StringField(required=True)
    nuggets = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Nugget), default=list)
```

My question is how can I ensure that the nuggets are stored and retrieved in a particular order (lets say insertion order)? The most efficient way is to emulate a deque structure right? SO how can I do that with mongoengine? If that's possible can I use the SortedListField of mongoengine to have the same effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to manage this in your application - always `push` to the list.  Otherwise you  have to ensure that you save (overwrite) the list in the order you want it to be in - the downsides of that are you have to be careful not to introduce a race condition in your code.  For that reason I'd advocate just using a push operation - see: http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/guide/querying.html?highlight=push#atomic-updates